# Why do my plots in python subplot come out in different sizes?

Tags: python, subplot

I am plotting two graphs in two rows and one column but they are coming out in different sizes. I have tried various fixes I have seen on Stack Overflow (grid spec, aspects, ratios) but they don't work. Any other ideas?

Here's the relevant bit of code and the figure [subplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CrX1.png):

```
directory=(pst1,pst2)
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
count = 1
for run in directory:
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,count)
    if count==1:
        cs1 = plt.contourf(lon,lat,pst1, np.arange(150,1500,150),extend='both',cmap = 'jet')
        contour=plt.contour(lon,lat,pst1, np.arange(150,1500,150), linestyles=':',linewidth=0.5,colors='k')
        plt.clabel(contour, fontsize=11, inline=1, fmt='%1.0f')
        plt.title('(a)',fontsize=12)
    if count==2:
        cs2 = plt.contourf(lon,lat,pst2, np.arange(150,1500,150),extend='both',cmap = 'jet')
        contour=plt.contour(lon,lat,pst2, np.arange(150,1500,150), linestyles=':',linewidth=0.5,colors='k')
        plt.clabel(contour, fontsize=11, inline=1, fmt='%1.0f')
        plt.title('(b)',fontsize=12)
    plt.xlabel('Longitude',  fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel('Latitude', fontsize=12)
    count=count+1
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs1, label = 'Pa', orientation = 'horizontal')
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(10,12)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib colorbar change axis size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043008/matplotlib-colorbar-change-axis-size)

Comment: Thanks for this link. Close enough for me to figure it out.